# Visual Studio Stop Refactoring Away Using In Specific Area

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, pragma, automated-refactoring

Usually, I can disable an annoying warning by wrapping two `pragma warning disable` statements around it. For instance:

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0060
public static int MultiplyByZero(int Number)
    => 0;
#pragma warning restore IDE0060
```

However, consider the following situation:

I have a file that uses many static classes all in the same namespace. They are very predictably named:

```
using static MyLib.Class0;
using static MyLib.Class1;
using static MyLib.Class2;
...
using static MyLib.Class9;
```

However, my class does not always use all these static classes. After one edit, it might only use `Class0`, `Class3`, and `Class4`. After another, it might only use `Class1, Class3, and Class6`. But I know that it is always going to use some of those classes.

When I attempt to save my file, Visual Studio naturally wants to refactor away all the unused `using`s. I told it to do that, after all, and I do still want that to happen for other unused `using`s, just not these.

Visual Studio did not provide the ID for removing unnecessary `using`s, but I looked it up on Google, and found it was `IDE0005`. So, as any good programmer would, I put that around my `using`s:

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0005
using static MyLib.Class0;
using static MyLib.Class1;
using static MyLib.Class2;
...
using static MyLib.Class9;
#pragma warning restore IDE0005
```

Visual Studio agreed with me that the `pragma`s were necessary, since it didn't lighten them as it usually does with unnecessary `pragma`s. I assumed that meant it would do what I wanted. However, when I clicked save, my `using`s disappeared anyway.

I looked at Intellisense's suggestions for other types of `pragma` besides `warning`. There was only `checksum`, whose documentation looked rather scary, and unrelated to my problem.

How can I make Visual Studio keep specific `using` statements?

To be clear, I am not looking for a file-wide or project-wide solution. There are other places where I would like that feature. I just need a way to mark a specific bit of code such that no `using`s will be removed.

**Edit:**

As multiple users in the comments have noted, this is not default behavior for Visual Studio. I have "Remove unnecessary imports or usings" selected in **Configure Code Cleanup**. I didn't occur to me that not everyone did that. So I guess the question really is, "How can I disable Code Cleanup for a specific few lines of code".

Comment: `when I clicked save, my usings disappeared anyway` - AFAIK, that is not standard behaviour of Visual Studio, it suspect it is caused either by a VS setting (if such a setting exists, not sure, maybe **[this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup)**) or else by a Plugin/Extension that is installed. My advice is to look through all those and see if you can disable it somewhere.

Comment: @PeterB That isn't an option, unfortunately. I've edited my question to explain why.

Comment: To be clear, I do not have any extensions, but for Nsight, which I never use.

Comment: Ok I see. It might work to change them to `global using` statements, [see here for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

Comment: How frequently do you edit that file with change of usings and why is that?

Comment: What do you mean about `disappeared  away`? Do you mean the text was deleted? Visual Studio itself does not automatically delete code when saving.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I just realized that. I've edited my question (again).

Comment: Currently, there is no such option in Visual Studio. You could request a feature on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/dotnet/suggest) and post link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As users in the comments have stated, there does not currently exist such a feature in Visual Studio. Hopefully such a feature will be created in the future, but none exist yet.

Until then, I have worked around the problem by commenting out then unnecessary usings. Then, when they are necessary, I can simply uncomment them to use them.

Thanks anyway to those who tried. Happy coding.